# react-abc: MIDI playback on iOS devices has several issues (missing notes, inconsistent tempo, unwanted sustain)

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, midi, abcjs

I'm using the `react-abc` package to enable MIDI playback on an app I'm working on.

Only on iOS (tested on iOS13) devices are there several issues with the MIDI playback. The 3 issues I've noticed after several attempts are:

1. Notes are sustained (early notes are still playing over later notes)
2. Some notes simply don't get played.
3. Notes are played at inconsistent tempo

A C Major scale is generated in MIDI with the following line, after importing `react-abc`:

```js
<Midi notation="CDEFGABc" />
```

But given that I've had audio playback issues with iOS before, I have reason to believe the issue isn't the `react-abc` package itself, but something with iOS itself. With previous audio issues, I was able to solve it by changing the audio filetype. But since this is generated MIDI, I don't have control over the filetype at all.

Here's a simple code sandbox demonstration of issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-einstein-0itci?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Please close the NotAllowedError and play the MIDI again to hear the problem I described above. The NotAllowedError is NOT my problem here.